# Autofilling pdf from Indesing.

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, interactive, adobe-acrobat

I'm wondering if it's possible to create an interactive pdf from an existing file.

Basically I have a Catalog/Pricelist with over 1000 items. What I want to achieve is to create page that would serve as an order form. 
So a dealer or client can write item number and pdf will match the number with it's price.

I know that with interactive pdf I can do simple math but is it possible to use it as a simply "find & place" function?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the search method but another solution would be create an option type input (combo box) order by categories. The client can select the product in the specific group of items.
Here a small tut to know how to achieve this:
http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=2063950&seqNum=3

Answer (score 1):

Some (many) years ago, I equipped several (PDF) catalogs with an order form. There are different possible approaches.

In some cases, we added a checkbox, or a button "buy it", which then transferred the item number and description to the order form page, where the user had to enter the number of ordering units.

In other cases, we added a text field where the user could directly enter the number of items, which then triggered an entry in the order form.

The actual order form could either be part of the catalog document, or come along as a separate document, where a uni- or bi-directional communication between the documents is set up.

Prices are another issue. But even here, we got the possibility to enter/update customer specific prices. In other cases, no prices were included at all.

These projects were all done before InDesign allowed for "interactive" documents, and were using Acrobat Pro to author; these documents do work in Reader.

If there is interest to further discuss a possible project, please feel free to contact me in private.

Comment: Hi, as stackexchange don't allow PMs and instant messages can you develop your answer?

Comment: As it would get quite specific for the individual use case, it is difficult to elaborate the answer here. I was mistaken, and thought a contact information would be in the profile, which isn't; therefore, try eMail to max at prodok dot com and refer to my stackexchange message. (note to moderator… if this is not appropriate, please let me know and I will correct this comment)